# Extracting date last saved and the name of the person who commented in MS Word doc in php

Tags: php

I want to extract the date last saved,the name of the person who commented and the number of characters from the Microsoft word document in php.

I searched the web, but mostly the libraries can create or format word files, they do not have the ability to extract date last saved and the name of the person who commented. Till now I have been successful in getting the number of lines, characters, any good suggestion for date last saved and name of the person who commented?

Comment: [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) can read a Word file and provide access to those document properties

Comment: @MarkBaker I saw PHP Word too, they do not have any such thing in their documentation. Do you know something that could help me out?

Comment: Load the document and the use the `getDocInfo()` method.... that will return a `DocInfo` object

Comment: @MarkBaker Can it return the comment present on the file as well?

Comment: I don't know about comments - I haven't been involved in all aspects of the project. I know about the metadata, because I wrote that code - but I suspect that they are accessible (Excel comments are accessible through PHPExcel, so I'd guess that Word comments are accessible too), though you might have to search through the API to find how to access them

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the help. I will try your code

Answer (score 1):

Using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord),
load the document and then use the document's `getDocInfo()` method.... that will return a `DocInfo` object.

The `DocInfo` object has methods for:

- getCreator()
- getLastModifiedBy()
- getCreated()         // Creation date (as a timestamp)
- getModified()        // Modification date (as a timestamp)
- getTitle()
- getDescription()
- getSubject()
- getKeywords()
- getCategory()
- getCompany()
- getManager()

and pretty much any value stored as a document property in the file's metadata